# I'm trying to use a while loop instead of a for loop. How would I change this code so that it works using a while loop in python?

Tags: python

```
# Generating Hollow Pyramid Pattern Using Stars

row = int(input('Enter number of rows required: '))

for i in range(row):
    for j in range(row-i):
        print(' ', end='') # printing space required and staying in same line

    for j in range(2*i+1):
        if j==0 or j==2*i or i==row-1:
            print('*',end='')
        else:
            print(' ', end='')
    print() # printing new line
```

I've tried swapping the (for) for (while <= .... etc) and add in i = 1 and i += 1 at the end but none seem to work.

Comment: could you show the code of what you have tried please?

Comment: *WHY* would you want to do such a thing?  When you have a predetermined range to iterate over, a `for` loop is vastly more appropriate than a `while` loop.

Comment: You can use `print(' '*(row-i),end='')` instead of that first `for j` loop.

Comment: This doesn't work as-is (the output doesn't look like a pyramid, anyway).  I'd suggest getting your `for` loop implementation working before thinking of ways to make it more difficult.

Comment: The indentation is all over the place, but it looks like you are (incorrectly) reusing the name `j` inside the second loop.

Comment: I have formatted the code to what I imagine you actually meant to post.  Hopefully, that was the right thing to do - it certainly fixes the confusion over whether the code works now or not.

Comment: What about this? https://onlinegdb.com/KuWQPE5wx  Or did I misunderstand the question?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code above, are you sure that you are adding the integer increment within the while loop?

for example,

```
i = 1
while i <= 10:
  do_something
  i+=1
```

will stop after 10 cycles, but

```
i = 1
while i <= 10:
  do_something
i+=1
```

will go on forever